# Using \InsertChunk on examdesign class to create testbank

Tags: exam

I've using the `examdesign` class to create exams and it can do almost everything I want.  But I find that I've been repeating myself as I reuse old exams as practice exams and quiz problems. I'd like to create a bank of test problems and it seems that this can almost be accomplished using the `\InsertChunk` function provided by the `examdesign` class, but there seems to be a small bug.

I can almost accomplish my goal if I put the following in the main LaTeX file:

```
\documentclass{examdesign}

\IncludeFromFile{foo.tex}

\begin{examtop}
    Exam Instructions
\end{examtop}

\begin{document}

\begin{multiplechoice}

  \begin{question}
    Question text goes here.
    \choice[!]{0.31}
  \end{question}

  \InsertChunk{chunk name}

\end{multiplechoice}

\end{document}
```

And the following in a file named `foo.tex`:

```
\begin{chunk}{chunk name}
  \begin{question}
    Question 2 text goes here.
    \choice[!]{0.31}
  \end{question}
\end{chunk}
```

However, this setup breaks if I remove the first question.

I was wondering if anybody knew enough about the `examdesign` class to propose a modification or a workaround so that I could keep all my questions in `foo.tex`.

Comment: Your code will produce errors as it is now (apparently you need to provide some value for `\class` in the preamble).

Comment: I am getting `! LaTeX Error: There's no line here to end.` as of now.

Comment: I've edited the code to define the `examtop` environment which I believe fixes the compilation errors.

Answer (score 1):

[`examdesign`](http://ctan.org/pkg/examdesign/) uses an odd (to me) method of finding the "stuff before the questions". It literally gathers up everything before the first `\begin` and marks that as the instructions.

```
% \begin{macro}{\get@instructions}
% This macro collects everything between it and the next |\begin| token.  It then
% calls the |\find@instructions@end| macro to check whether the |\begin| token
% belongs to the \textsf{question} environment or some other environment.
%    \begin{macrocode}
\long\def\get@instructions#1\begin{\@toklist=\expandafter{\the\@toklist#1}%
  \find@instructions@end}
%    \end{macrocode}
% \end{macro}
```

I think one could rewrite this to define an instructions environment, but maybe that makes the questions unnecessarily wordy.

The `\find@instructions@end` is pretty particular, and will only stop gobbling when it finds `\begin{question}` or `\begin{block}`.  The `\begin{block}` just delays the problem, as it uses a similar method to find the instructions for the block.

In other words, I don't see a simple way to do this without changing the syntax expected by the package.  Certainly, to me this looks like a question for the package author.